# How I can add N ImageViews on screen at random location. As AbsoluteLayout is deprecated

Tags: android

How I can add N ImageViews on screen at random location. As AbsoluteLayout is deprecated. what can I do?
I just want to display Images on screen at random locations.

Comment: create random `x` and `y` positions, and set ImageView's `x` and `y` as those created earlier.

Comment: Which layout I should use apart from AbsoluteLayout, as it is deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RelativeLayout

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);

ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);

Random r = new Random();

params.leftMargin = r.nextInt(width);
params.topMargin = r.nextInt(height);;
rl.addView(iv, params);
```